# ¿Como agrupar dos tablas de manera dinámica en una matriz?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día apreciados señores...
Recientemente recibí apoyo para resolver un tema, dejo el enlace abajo:

[Generar matriz de datos con LEFT JOINS en SQL Server](http://Generar%20matriz%20de%20datos%20con%20LEFT%20JOINS%20en%20SQL%20Server)
Lo que pude resolver con esto (mas algunas modificaciones con SQL Dinámico ), fue la generación de una matriz de datos, tal como la que muestro a continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:

La parte de generar SQL Dinámico, lo resuelvo con este script :

```
select Conteo, #row, 'max (case when enf.Nro = ' + cast(Conteo as varchar(4) )+ ' ' +'then enf.' + Campo + ' ' +'else null end) as ' +Campo+cast (Conteo as varchar(4)) CreacionCase
from
(
    select #vt.Conteo Conteo,   tt.Campo Campo,#row
    from ##ValoresPorTabla #vt 
    cross apply
    (
        select Campo , 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (  order by  Campo) #row
        from TablaCampoInformes
        where Tabla ='Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS' and Campo <> 'Id_FichaIOS'
    )tt
    where #vt.Tabla ='Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS'
    --order by Conteo, #row
)x  order by Conteo, #row
```

El cual me genera la cantidad de case que se requiera con base a la tabla **##ValoresPorTabla** , la cual me indica cuantas columnas debo generar para cada campo; como muestro a continuación :

```html
Conteo      #row                 CreacionCase
----------- -------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           1                    max (case when enf.Nro = 1 then enf.Fecha_Enfermedad else null end) as Fecha_Enfermedad1
1           2                    max (case when enf.Nro = 1 then enf.Id_Enfermedad else null end) as Id_Enfermedad1
1           3                    max (case when enf.Nro = 1 then enf.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad else null end) as Id_Tipo_Enfermedad1
2           1                    max (case when enf.Nro = 2 then enf.Fecha_Enfermedad else null end) as Fecha_Enfermedad2
2           2                    max (case when enf.Nro = 2 then enf.Id_Enfermedad else null end) as Id_Enfermedad2
2           3                    max (case when enf.Nro = 2 then enf.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad else null end) as Id_Tipo_Enfermedad2
3           1                    max (case when enf.Nro = 3 then enf.Fecha_Enfermedad else null end) as Fecha_Enfermedad3
3           2                    max (case when enf.Nro = 3 then enf.Id_Enfermedad else null end) as Id_Enfermedad3
3           3                    max (case when enf.Nro = 3 then enf.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad else null end) as Id_Tipo_Enfermedad3
4           1                    max (case when enf.Nro = 4 then enf.Fecha_Enfermedad else null end) as Fecha_Enfermedad4
4           2                    max (case when enf.Nro = 4 then enf.Id_Enfermedad else null end) as Id_Enfermedad4
4           3                    max (case when enf.Nro = 4 then enf.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad else null end) as Id_Tipo_Enfermedad4
5           1                    max (case when enf.Nro = 5 then enf.Fecha_Enfermedad else null end) as Fecha_Enfermedad5
5           2                    max (case when enf.Nro = 5 then enf.Id_Enfermedad else null end) as Id_Enfermedad5
5           3                    max (case when enf.Nro = 5 then enf.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad else null end) as Id_Tipo_Enfermedad5
```

Sin embargo las cosas se me complicaron, ya que, en la matriz necesito agrupar dos tablas como lo muestro en el siguiente ejemplo generado en excel como medio de ilustración :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar, las columnas se agrupan de la siguiente manera

Enfermedades|Medicamentos|Medicamentos|..|n Medicamentos|Enfermedades..Medicamentos

Por ejemplo:

El Id_FichaIOS 181, tiene dos enfermedades, pero solo recibió medicamento para una.

El Id_FichaIOS 199, tiene también dos enfermedades, para el código Id_Enfermedad = 20 recibió dos medicamentos y para el código Id_Enfermedad = 2 recibió solamente uno.

Dejo la estructura de tablas y la data relacionada al ejemplo que planteo.

```html
CREATE TABLE #Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS(
 [Id_Enfermead_FichaIOS_Pac] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Id_FichaIOS] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Id_Tipo_Enfermedad] [int] NULL,
 [Id_Enfermedad] [int] NULL
) 
GO

insert into #Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS (Id_Enfermead_FichaIOS_Pac, Id_FichaIOS, Id_Tipo_Enfermedad, Id_Enfermedad)
values  (19,181,'2017-06-03 00:00:00.000', 3,523),
  (20,181,'2017-01-17 00:00:00.000', 3,287),
  (35,199,'2017-05-15 00:00:00.000', 1,20 ),
  (36,199,'2017-05-31 00:00:00.000', 2,2 )



CREATE TABLE #Medicamento_Administrado(
 [Id_Enferdad_Ficha_IOS_Pac] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Id_FichaIOS] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Id_TipoMedicamento] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Id_Medicamento] [int] NULL,
 [Id_ViaAdministracion] [int] NOT NULL
)
GO

insert into #Medicamento_Administrado (Id_Enferdad_Ficha_IOS_Pac, Id_FichaIOS, Id_Medicamento,Id_TipoMedicamento,Id_ViaAdministracion)
values (20,181,3,79,3),
  (35,199,2,17,2),
  (35,199,2,18,2),
  (36,199,6,1,2)
```

Hasta ahora no encuentro una manera de resolverlo, alguna idea ??? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final encontré solución en SQL Dinámico.

```
select Conteo, NroCampo,
case when Tabla = 'enf' 
        then 'max (case when enf.Nro = ' + cast(Conteo as varchar(4) )+ ' ' +'then enf.' + Campo + ' ' +'else null end) as ' +Campo+cast (NroCampo as varchar(4))  
        else 'max (case when med.Nro = ' + cast(Conteo as varchar(4) )+ ' ' +'then med.' + Campo + ' ' +'else null end) as ' +Campo+cast (NroCampo as varchar(4))  end CampoCase
from
(           
    select   #vt.Conteo Conteo,   datos.Campo Campo, datos.Tabla, datos.NroCampo, Row, Nro
    from ##ValoresPorTabla #vt 
    outer apply
    (
        select Conteo, Campo ,   Tabla, NroCampo,  
        ROW_NUMBER() over (  partition by Tabla order by  Conteo, NroCampo ) Row,  
        ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select null)) Nro           
        from
        (
            select '' Conteo, Campo ,  'enf' Tabla, ROW_NUMBER() over (  order by  Campo) NroCampo
            from TablaCampoInformes
            where Tabla ='Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS' and Campo <> 'Id_FichaIOS'
            union all 
            select Conteo, Campo, data.Tabla, NroCampo 
            from ##ValoresPorTabla #vt 
            cross apply 
            (
                select Campo ,  'med' Tabla, ROW_NUMBER() over (  order by  Campo) NroCampo
                from TablaCampoInformes
                where Tabla ='Medicamento_Administrado' and Campo <> 'Id_FichaIOS'
            )data
            where #vt.Tabla ='Medicamento_Administrado'
            )x 
    )datos  where #vt.Tabla = 'Medicamento_Administrado'    
)datos
```